# Powershell - Generate and execute scripts on the fly programmatically

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a requirement to read a feature-set definition and generate powershell for each feature set.

**For example -**

> Feature 1 -
>   1. II7.0 to be installed on a system 
>   2. Create custom app pool
>   3. provide proper user credentials...etc
>
> Feature 2 -  Write some config data to registry

**and so on...**

Now, I have a Wizard kind of UI for collecting user data & clicking on Next should generate powershell ps1 file [specific to that feature] & execute the same on the fly.

How can I achieve the same ? You can assume .Net 4.0 framework for this.

> Something like what is available in IIS 8 Beta
>   -http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2012/03/05/powershell-script-generation-in-iis-configuration-editor.aspx

**NB:** I have still not decided whether to have a single PS1 file for all feature or one for each because while executing the script at the end, if say, 5th feature fails, I need to rollback all the earlier operations. That is again a question to ponder upon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Wix (which is designed for the same) an option?

Answer (score 0):

Not a DIRECT answer to your question, but something that you should know: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/bruceky/how-to-embedding-powershell-within-a-c-application